# How to force Thunar to default to detailed list view?

Tags: 18.04, thunar

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.  I would like to set Thunar to always show a detailed list view for not root version of Thunar.  I can open Thunar, go into the preferences, and set the current instance to show detailed lists views like this.
[image]

But then, when I reboot and open Thunar the icons view default is back as shown below.
[image]

I would like to permanently set Thunar to show detailed lists always using my non-root account. Other users posting here post similar advice found on-line that changing these settings ought to apply after reboot but they do not.  I can set Thunar to display detailed list views if I open Thunar using sudo.  Then after rebooting and opening Thunar using sudo does show detailed list views.

How do I force Thunar to default to detailed list view after reboot for a non sudo version of Thunar?

Comment: When it starts fresh, thunar should pick up the settings of the thunar window that was closed last. For me it does on 19.10.

Comment: Make sure that you are the owner of `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/` as in there is a `thunar.xml` file that contains the settings to Thunar.  This is acting like the settings are not owned by you or that you do not have write permissions to the file.  Also there are settings in `~/.config/Thunar/` as well.  It might be best to make sure that you are the owner of your entire home `~` folder.